# Is there a better way to plot an array?

Tags: matlab, plot

I would please like to know, if there is a better way to plot a nx2 matrix

This is how I do:

```
%... matrix
 A = [2 4 2 6 8; 9 8 7 6 4];

 %plot
 column1 = A(:,1);
 column2 = A(:,2);
 plot(column1, column2, 'r+')
```

1. Is there a possibility like for example:

```
 plot(A, 'r+') %???
```

Why does this not work?

```
I also can't get how this work
 plot(A, 'r+') %???
```

I expect, that each row consists of x and y coordinate respectively.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your questions are all answered by [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that the array should be plotted so that the first row is x and the second row is y, but the format of your code indicates that you were trying to plot them by columns instead.

Try the following code and, if it doesn't produce the desired plot, please be more specific with your question.

```
A = [2 4 2 6 8; 9 8 7 6 4];
x_row = A(1,:);
y_row = A(2,:);
plot(x_row,y_row)
```

If you want to change this from a line plot to a dot plot, simply include that in the end of your `plot` statement as you'd done so previously.

e.g.,

```
plot(x_row,y_row, 'go')
```

Comment: you're right, the matrix should be A = [2 4; 2 6; 8 9; 8 7; 6 4]; But I thing the way to plot is how I did on the top of my post. Thank you anyway for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this capability exists.

If you use the free [Matlog toolbox](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/) for logistics engineering, the code would be `pplot(A,'r+')` -- see the first example for [`pplot`](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/MatlogRef.htm#pplot).

```
A = [2 4 2 6 8; 9 8 7 6 4].';
pplot(A,'r+')
```

You can adjust properties the same as you would normally.

```
p = pplot(A,'r+');
p.MarkerSize = 12;     % Adjust marker size
```

*Is this a better way*?  I don't know. That depends. It does come in handy sometimes, especially if you have coordinate data in a **nx2** array.

---

The [Matlog toolbox](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/) is a free toolbox for Logistics Engineering written and maintained by [Professor Michael Kay](https://www.ise.ncsu.edu/people/kay/) at NC State University. It receives regular updates.

I use it often for certain applications (it has several high-utility functions). Anecdotally, I've found it compatible for MATLAB R2018b and earlier.

> The toolbox contains functions for solving the following types of
>   problems:
>
> **Facility location:** Continuous minisum facility location, alternate location-allocation (ALA) procedure, discrete uncapacitated facility
>   location
>   **Freight transport:** Transport charges for TL and LTL, total logistics cost, aggregate multiple shipments
>   **Vehicle routing:** VRP, VRP with time windows, traveling salesman problem (TSP)
>   **Networks:** Shortest path, min cost network flow, minimum spanning tree problems
>   **Geocoding:** U.S. city or ZIP code to longitude and latitude, longitude and latitude to nearest city, Mercator projection plotting
>   **Layout:** Steepest descent pairwise interchange (SDPI) heuristic for QAP
>   **General purpose:** Linear programming using the revised simplex method procedure, mixed-integer linear programming, and Cplex
>   interface to MILP
>   **Data:** U.S. cities with populations of at least 10,000, U.S. highway network (Oak Ridge National Highway Network); U.S. 3- and
>   5-digit ZIP codes; U.S. Census Block Group data

Source: [Matlog documentation](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/)